# Text field inside <p> tags falls below it

Tags: theming, entities

I've created a custom twig template in which I'm placing a text field inside a

tag like so:

```
<p>{{ content.field_sample_text }}</p>
```

It renders the content of that field just fine but when I inspect it, it seems to create a new div below the

tag and places its contents in that div like so:

```
<p></p>
<div>
  Content of the field
</div>
<p></p>
```

There's an extra p tag at the end as well which is also confusing. How can I ensure that my text field renders inside the original p tag as intended so that I can style it properly?

Comment: Presumably your field template wraps things in an empty div? A p cannot contain a div, so what you're seeing is the browser trying to recover the invalid markup

Comment: That was exactly what was happening, thank you! I was using the stable theme's field.html.twig template and that makes all the content be inside divs. If you can put this down as an answer I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Stable like theme you can see that the field is wrapped around a `div` tag.
You can rewrite `field.html.twig` with your theme suggestions and edit the markup.